# Autocomplete MaterialUI - How can I set a default value in Grouped autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, autocomplete, material-ui

I am using Autocomplete grouped component? I want that a default value already selected when component loads or refresh.

Code is below code

```
<Autocomplete
    id="grouped-demo"
    className={'input-dropdown'}
    options={options.sort((a, b) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter))}
    groupBy={(option) => option.firstLetter}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
    onChange={this.linkDropdownChange}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="grouped Collection" variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

Comment: use `defaultValue`

Comment: "defaultValue" is not working in "grouped-demo".

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you got two options

> Controllable states
> The component has two states that can be controlled:
>
> the "value" state with the value/onChange props combination. This
> state represents the value selected by the user, for instance when
> pressing Enter. the "input value" state with the
> inputValue/onInputChange props combination. This state represents the
> value displayed in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Done!!!!!

Autocomplete grouped component uses `defaultValue` as `object` not a `string`